# Matlab 2D function subsequence similarity

Tags: matlab, 2d, similarity

If i have 2 functions, let's say f(x) and g(x) and i want to find the longest portion of f that is similar to some portion of g, how can i do that?

For example, consider the figure below: [image]

it is pretty evident they are enough similar to each other in the starting position, but what if they where in random position?
That's the point, i need to discover the longest similar portion(s) ... some hints?
In my case the two "functions" are an array rappresentation of two songs, and i want to find the most similar part of them, so they are supposed to be

1. different in the 99% of the rappresentation ( see the second example below )[image]
2. Just barely similar in a random position : except for the orizontal lines, a perfect matching is never expected to be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using cross-correlation ([xcor](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html)).

This method computes the correlation of 2 signals for each "offset" between them. The highest correlated point will be the offset you need to give to `signal2` to match `signal1`. Read the documentation for examples and usage.

Comment: This works even if the "signals" are hugely dissimilar? i edited my post to meke more clear my goal :)

Comment: You say in the question "i want to find the longest portion of f that is similar to some portion of g". This is the way of doing it. If the singals are not similar, when you look for similarities, then you may not find them, rigth? Its a logical assumption. Still, this method will give you the most similar location, even if most means "not really similar"

Comment: @Fujitina If you want a portion, then you may need to compute the `xcorr` for different lengths of `f`, that is also an option